# Maven project to java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to maven. I had downloaded a maven project from SVN. I figured it out that it was not as a java project in SVN itself. Result is, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> it gives no options but an error message that the project is not in the build path. and there is no build path option too. The project is a kind of developed so I cant create again as new maven project. So, I downloaded the project and added .classpath and .project files to the project. Now I got buildpath option. but it still is not a complete java project. Can any of you please explain what I need to do to make it as a complete java project...

Thanks in advance for taking time to read this and replaying it...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're editing in eclipse in which case, from the command line "mvn eclipse:eclipse"  will get you everything set up.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modern Eclipse, e.g. version 4.3. It should come with the "m2e" (Maven 2 integration for Eclipse) plugin per-installed. If not, you can install it from the Kepler update site.

You can import a Maven project into Eclipse using *File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project*.